# box-sizing is causing my tooltips to be positioned in the wrong place

Tags: jquery, html, css

I deleted my previous question and reopened a new one as now I can pin point the problem myself and ask for guidance.

Now I have a website here: http://msdixon.co.uk/test123/

Now if you use the toolbox on the right hand side with the three icons in it. The tooltips are out of position. I've managed to find out that the css causing this issue is:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you open developer tools and `codebarracksUI.css` and remove this you'll see everything works fine. However, with it enabled the offset is wrong for the tooltip plugin I am using. So the offset() of the toolbox items is incorrect. But this however fixes it.

I need help acquiring a solution which allows me to keep the css above as I need it for the grid system but help me resolve my issue with the tooltip having the incorrect position.

**EDIT:**
If i add this:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
```

to the `.main-sidebar` class this resolves my problem. Can anybody explain why this happens?

Reference: .main-sidebar css:

```
.main-sidebar {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 50px;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 230px;
    z-index: 810;
    background-color: #272b35;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out,width .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .3s ease-in-out,width .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .3s ease-in-out,width .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out,width .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: On Firefox it works well with `border-box` and is broken with `content-box`.

Comment: works on my firefox :/

Comment: When adding content-box I get the scrollbar on all browsers which Is meant to be there. I just don't understand why this behaviour is occurring. Also I hope it works on all browsers too :/

Comment: @Oriol I didn't update the stylesheet on the webserver. Might be okay for you now.